# Get value from dataset at given column name and row name in R

Tags: r, hash, get

Now I have two dataframes. One of the is huge and acts like a library, the other one is small and empty, it only contains column names and row names, let's call it *target*. Now I try to fill the *target* getting the corresponding values from the *library*.

Let's say *target* looks like this:

```
Ind   Dog  Cat  Fish  Bird
A     0    0    0     0
B     0    0    0     0
C     0    0    0     0 
D     0    0    0     0
```

What I want is something that achieves this:

```
for(i in 1:dim(target[,1]) {
  for(j in 1:dim(target[1,]) {
      target[i,j]<-get(library, rowname=target[i,], colname=target[,j]
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your code, you can try something like this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(target){
  for(j in 1:ncol(target){
    target[i,j]<- library[  row.names(target)[i] , col.names(target)[j] ] 
  }}
```

I assume that `library` has corresponding row and column names.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: glad to help, please accept the answer if you like it :)